# generate multiple tables from multiple selections of scatterplot in shiny R

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I have a scatterplot in a shiny dashbaord and would like to generate **two** different tables by selecting/highlighting different areas of the scatterplot. I am currently able to generate a single table by selecting/highlighting an area, however am not sure how to make this work for two tables/selections (or if that is even possible).

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thankyou

Sample code to generate a shiny dashboard with a scatterplot and highlight/generate a single table is provided below (and was taken from [here](https://mastering-shiny.org/action-graphics.html))

*Some more detail* : Ideally this process would be achieved by manually selecting/dragging an area over some points, generating the first table and then manually selecting/dragging an area over a different subset of points and generating the second table. After this, if another area is selected, it resets the first selection and table and then the next selection would reset the second selection and table.

```
ui <- fluidPage(

  plotOutput("plot", brush = "plot_brush"),
  tableOutput("data")
)
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
  }, res = 96)
  
  output$data <- renderTable({
    brushedPoints(mtcars, input$plot_brush)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this might be helpful. You can track which table (1 or 2) in `reactiveValues` as well as the data for each table. Let me know if this is what you had in mind. If you wanted to maintain the previous selection in the plot, I would think you may need to manually place a rectangle. A [github issue](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/2105) allowing for multiple selections of brushed points is an open issue (enhancement). Alternatively, you could tag points for each table based on [this approach](https://github.com/microsoft/TagAnomaly/issues/9).

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  plotOutput("plot", brush = "plot_brush"),
  h2("Table 1"),
  tableOutput("data1"),
  h2("Table 2"),
  tableOutput("data2")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  rv <- reactiveValues(table = 1,
                       data1 = NULL,
                       data2 = NULL)
  
  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) + geom_point()
  }, res = 96)
  
  my_data <- eventReactive(input$plot_brush, {
    if (rv$table == 1) {
      rv$table <- 2
      rv$data1 <- input$plot_brush
    } else {
      rv$table <- 1
      rv$data2 <- input$plot_brush
    }
    return(rv)
  })
  
  output$data1 <- renderTable({
    brushedPoints(mtcars, my_data()$data1)
  })
  
  output$data2 <- renderTable({
    brushedPoints(mtcars, my_data()$data2)
  })
  
}

shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: Thankyou so much! That does exactly what I want. Nice solution too. You rock! :)